# How to get the truth table without the expession?

Tags: circuit-analysis, truth-table

I am in my first year at university and I have been given the following assignment:

> Implement a support system for the safety of passengers inside motor vehicles.
>
> The system must ensure that the vehicle's ignition is only activated if some conditions of safety, that is, if driver and passenger have their safety belts fastened. If the safety conditions are not met, the system should display a warning light when the vehicle is on (K activated). If the warning signal is active, the system must prevent ignition (S activated).
>
> The system has the following input signals:
>
> - (CC) Driver Belt Sensor;
> - (CA) Companion Belt Sensor;
> - (A) Companion presence sensor;
> - (K) Vehicle key to establish general power;
> - (S) Momentary Start activation to promote ignition.
>
> Preparation:
>
> Get the simplified expressions of the Alert and Ignition outputs.

I tried to assemble the truth table but I can't find out what is the parameter of the operations to follow for the alarm (the values ​​of alert) or each possibility.

Here's the example of a similar problem's solution down below:

Assume that you get the following expressions:  = ~.  + ~ and çã = ~ + ~. So the door logic to use are: AND, OR and NOT.

I apologise if there are errors in my explanation, we've only done the truth table with the non-simplified expression (I know how to get the simplified expression through the V-K maps but I can't get my head around the results or alarm based on the inputs.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: step1: make a table of every possible permutation of input.  step2: add output columns and fill in the logic according to the statements.

Comment: Since this is a homework problem we will expect you to show us that you have made a **substantial** effort to solve this yourself. Show us **all** of your work, then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: @Abel my problem is in the fill in the logi acording to the statement part, usually I would get an expression like F=A*B  then would use it to get the output 1 or 0 in each permutation of output but I dont hae nothing like it in the result.

Comment: What inputs do you have?  What outputs do you have?  Draw a table with columns for the inputs and columns for the outputs.  Use the description from the assignment to fill the truth table. From the truth table, you can derive an expression, and from that the circuit.

Comment: You are doing fine. It looks okay with what you are doing. There is no need for table or mapping to begin with. Process can go the other way around. The questionnaire wants just "expressions".  Meantime the expression should be, in my opinion,   = . ~ + ~ and çã = ~ . K . . If a table is required, then use the expression to generate binary value table. Maps can base on that table now.

Comment: @jay thank you I managed to omplete a truth table then aplied the karnaugh maps to get   = . ~ + ~ and çã = ~ . .

Comment: @cobaltbasalt , you are welcome. I am glad to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than solve your homework, I'll present a different problem. I believe this is a lesson in turning the somewhat inconsistent and often illogical source of information that is language into a slightly more logical form that is a truth table.

The light shall turn on when the light switch is in the on position.  The light cannot turn on if there is a power outage.

Inputs:

A. The light switch is in the on position.

B. There is a power outage.

Output: The light is on

Step 1 would produce:

| The light switch is in the on position | There is a power outage | The light is on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | ? |
| T | F | ? |
| F | T | ? |
| F | F | ? |

What would the Output column be per step2, your understanding of lights, and power outages?

What if we add another input of the form:

A functioning backup generator can compensate for a power outage.

Input: The backup generator is functional.

Comment: Thank YOU !! I managed to solve the problem using your example.